# Which program runs $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart in Debian 9?

Tags: debian, systemd, xdg, autostart

Which program runs `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart` in Debian 9?

I tried putting the following `.desktop` file in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=test
Comment=test
NoDisplay=true
Exec=sh -c 'cat /proc/$$/status >~/test_output'
NotShowIn=GNOME;KDE;XFCE;
```

Its PPID is 1 (`systemd`),but I can't find how systemd handles the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart` entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is handled by desktop environments which implement the [Desktop Application Autostart Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/autostart-spec/). If you’re using the default desktop environment in Debian 9, GNOME, autostart applications are started by `gnome-session`.

I imagine the fact that your process ends up with `systemd` as its parent is because its original parent stops and leaves it running; processes whose parent dies are reparented to pid 1.